# parenthesized matches as an array (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

I seem to remember there was a way to access the parenthesized matches of a regex in Perl (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.) as an array, but now I can't seem to find that.  Neither `@+` and `@-` are what I mean.

**Edit:**
I should add that I want to access this array inside a `s///` (substitution), like so:

```
s/(foo)(bar)+(baz)/mySubst(@!)/e;
```

(if `@!` were the array I'm looking for)

Comment: Did you look under the couch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of a built-in magic array that holds all of the parenthesized groups, but that doesn't stop you from making one:

```
{package Match::Parens;
    sub TIEARRAY {bless []}
    sub FETCH {no strict 'refs'; ${$_[1] + 1}}
    sub FETCHSIZE {$#+}
    tie @!, __PACKAGE__;
}

sub mySubst {join ', ' => map ucfirst, @_}

my $str = 'foobarbarbaz';

$str =~ s/(foo)(bar)+(baz)/mySubst(@!)/e;

say $str;  # prints 'Foo, Bar, Baz'
```

Here we declare that `Match::Parens` will be the new implementation of the `@!` array with tie.  Each time it is accessed, it looks up the current match paren at that index.  The current implementation starts at 0 like arrays, you might want to change it to start at 1 like the `$1, $2, $3` vars.

Answer (score 1):

@array = $foo =~ m/(your)(reg)(exp)/;

Comment: This is kind of what I want, but need to be able to use it in `s///`... see my edit to the question

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of how it behaves with the global matching flag?

```
@matches = /x(.+?)y/g;   # Matching against $_
```

Matches will contain an array element for each match in the string.

I have never heard of what you're referring  too.  [This link](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=324748) may provide you some info to help you achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around. You can also access them as reference.

```
s/(foo)(bar)+(baz)/mySubst([$1,$2,$3,$4])/e;
```

This would be working nice, if you know upper bound of matching elements. This solution doesn't break with warnings.